# Asyncio don't return to the welcome function

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm learning to use async functions, and in this practice, I'm simulating a conversation with an IA. Everything goes fine until right after the program asks for a name but instead returns to the nice to meet you {} in the welcome function it continues to the create_user() function and when the create_user() function finishes it returns to the welcome function to ask to create a user.

## **THIS IS THE OUTPUT IM GETTING:**

```
>> Hello
>> Who are you?
>> What's your name? Moises
>> Tell me a user name you like: RD
>> Now tell me a password: 1234
>> User created!
>> Nice to meet you Moises!
>> would you like to create a user? y/n y
>> Nice, you have a username {user} and a password {}
>> now you are part of us!
```

## **THE CODE:**

```
    # practice.py

"""Simulating an IA using the asyncio function"""

import asyncio, time, os


def wait(): # To pause the conversation
    time.sleep(2)
    
async def welcome(): # the main function
    task = asyncio.create_task(data())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(create_user())

    os.system('cls')

    print(">> Hello")
    wait()
    print(">> Who are you?")
    wait()
    return_value = await task # wait for task (data) to return the value with the name
    print(f">> Nice to meet you {return_value}!")
    wait()

    ask = input(">> would you like to create a user? y/n ") # Asking to create a user yes or no
    if ask == 'y':
        user, password  =  await task2 # waiting for task2 (create_user) to return values
        print(">> Nice, you have a username {user} and a password {}")
        wait()
        print(">> now you are part of us!")
    else:
        print(">> You can not interact with me if you don't have a user")
        wait()
        print(">> See you!")
        quit()

async def data(): # User personal data
    global name
    name = input(">> What's your name? ")
    return name
    

async def  create_user(): # User account data
    user = input(">> Tell me a user name you like: ")
    passw =input(">> Now tell me a password: ")
    wait()
    print(">> User created!")
    return user, passw
    


    

# Run the program
asyncio.run(welcome())
```

Comment: Are you expecting the tasks to execute only when you await them? `asyncio.create_task` schedules the task straight away

Comment: When you await something, the event loop has a chance to run. It gives everything scheduled against it a chance to run before stopping. Since you’ve created two tasks, the second is able to run after the first completes. Really you should just use `return_value = await data()`. `create_task` should be used for things you want to run in the background while other asynchronous things are happening. I know you’re still learning but none of your code is actually asynchronous. I’d recommend checking out some tutorials before trying to dive right in.

Comment: Please use proper formatting in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, not all the tutorials I've seen are clear does is why I posted the doubt here

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
```

```
# practice.py

"""Simulating an IA using the asyncio function"""

import asyncio
import os


async def wait():  # To pause the conversation
    await asyncio.sleep(2)


async def welcome():  # the main function

    os.system('clear')

    print(">> Hello")
    await wait()
    print(">> Who are you?")
    await wait()

    # wait for task (data) to return the value with the name
    return_value = asyncio.create_task(data())
    await return_value
    print(f">> Nice to meet you {return_value.result()}!")
    await wait()

    # Asking to create a user yes or no
    ask = input(">> would you like to create a user? y/n ")
    if ask == 'y':
        task2 = asyncio.create_task(create_user())
        # waiting for task2 (create_user) to return values
        user, password = await task2
        print(f">> Nice, you have a username {user} and a password {password}")
        await wait()
        print(">> now you are part of us!")
    else:
        print(">> You can not interact with me if you don't have a user")
        await wait()
        print(">> See you!")
        quit()


async def data():  # User personal data
    global name
    name = input(">> What's your name? ")
    return name


async def create_user():  # User account data
    user = input(">> Tell me a user name you like: ")
    passw = input(">> Now tell me a password: ")
    await wait()
    print(">> User created!")
    return user, passw


# Run the program
asyncio.run(welcome())
```

Comment: Well organized and super easy to understand, thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).